# Best practice in SQL for storing users information?

Tags: sql, database

I am new to SQL Databases and was wondering if someone can show me what the best practice would be to store a user and their linked data which may be variable entries long. I am using python to add 2D List information to my DB: `[user, name, [photo1, photo2,...]]` is the format for each index of the main list.

My example is  want a user, and they can have X amount of photos to their name. Each user has a primary key id and a title(name).

My thoughts from what I have read is to have a main table where each user has a primary key id and a name along with a photo id.

| ID | Title | Photo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | 1 |
| 2 | James | 2 |

Then have a second table which would store the photo links and reference the photo id of that user in the previous table?

| ID | link |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Image1.jpg |
| 1 | Image2.jpg |
| 2 | Image5.jpg |
| 2 | Image4.jpg |
| 2 | Image3.jpg |

Leaving me with information i could grab such as:

```
User id 1: Bob: (www.Image1.jpg, www.Image2.jpg)

User id 2: James(www.Image3.jpg, www.Image4.jpg, www.Image5.jpg)
```

**Is this the best practice? or is there a better way to do it?**

Comment: Nearly.  You don't really need the "Photo" column.  The unique ID is enough to act as the foreign key.

Comment: You should settle on a sensible naming convention for table and column names though, as that ID column in the second table being a photo ID will be quite confusing to maintainers.